# MySQL query with two identicals fields

Tags: mysql, sql

the DB looks like this, and I need a query to get each stat with the idstat, the user downloader, and the user creator. Without adding a line "user_creator" in the stat table.
I should be able to get the user creator with stat.contentidcontent > content.iduser but I can't reach it, I always get the iduser_downloader in the iduser_creator column.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Just join the three tables. Please show us your query and we'll tell you what's wrong about it. If you want both users, you'll have to join the user table twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must join 2 copies of `user` to get the downloader and the creator:

```
select s.idstad,
       ud.iduser downloader_id, ud.name downloader_name,
       uc.iduser creator_id, uc.name creator_name
from stat s
inner join user ud on ud.iduser = s.user_iduserdownloader
inner join content c on c.idcontent = s.content_idcontent
inner join user uc on uc.iduser = c.user_iduser_creator
```

Comment: Thanks it works. There a just a missing coma after the first line ;) .